# How to move up/down an item in a table

Tags: java, swt

Following is an UI:
[image]

There is an Up button and a down button in the UI, when clicking the Up/down button, the selected item(e.g. lib/logger.jar) in the left table(**I assume it is a table**, because I will create a table to show the items in my Application) will be moved up/down.

Question: How to add function to the Up/Down button, so the item in the table will be moved after clicking the Up/Down button?

BTW, I am using Java SWT/JFace.

Comment: Can you provide the code for moving the table rows up and down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a table, you will work with `TableItems`.  To move a TableItem, you have to dispose the one you want to move and create a new one using the constructor that receives an index as one of its arguments.  This index is where the new TableItem will be placed.